# MySQL CASE EnumInt WHEN Varchar ELSE Int returning as BLOB - How to cast as a Varchar?

Tags: mysql, casting, enums, persistence, blob

The following returns a BLOB, how can I convert this else value to a VARCHAR to fix my problem?

```
SELECT
    CASE EnumID
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Red'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Green'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Blue'
        ELSE EnumID
    END AS EnumValue
FROM Table
```

In MSSQL/TSQL I use `ELSE CAST([EnumID] AS VARCHAR(100))` but MySQL complains.

All I want is a failover should this stored procedure not know a new enum value to manage code vs. main database vs. data warehouse data persistence.

Bound to be an obvious answer...

---

Apparently the problem seems to be using VARCHAR? Just found that `CAST(EnumID AS CHAR(20))` works fine in the case switch.

Sigh... why do I bother posting all I need is a Rubber Duck to talk to...

Comment: does it have the brackets [EnumID] in the code?

Comment: post the answer to the question as an answer. then check it as an answer. it helps with rep.

Comment: Already tried to but was forced to wait 8 hours first

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `cast`

```
SELECT 
    CAST(CASE EnumID 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Red' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Green' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Blue' 
        ELSE EnumID 
    END AS VARCHAR(20)) AS EnumValue
FROM `Table`
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: I like this solution more. Thanks

Comment: Not working for me:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(20)) AS EnumValue' at line 7